# Why do two different Mathematica files with the same ODEs substituted with the same values give me different outputs?

Tags: differential-equations, replacement

I have a big struggle with numerical solution of a set of 3 ODE equations in one .nb file. This is completely wrong when I when use NDSolve[] command for them with previous substitution of certain values to parameters in these equations.

However, when I open different .nb file, paste that set of 3 ODEs and substitute the same values to parameters but right in this new file the NDSolve[] command works well.

Where is the problem? Is it possible that opening just an another .nb file makes such a difference in computation?

These are values to parameters:

```
Subscript[φ, start] = 0.7853981633;
Subscript[l, 1] = 1;
Subscript[l, 2] = 4;
Subscript[l, 3] = 1;
Subscript[l, 4] = 2;

Subscript[m, 12] = 4;
Subscript[m, 3] = 0;
Subscript[m, 4] = 0;
Subscript[m, pw] = 100;
Subscript[m, D] = 1
g = 9.81;
```

Thank you for your help.

These are ODEs with values of parameters substituted in one .nb file for which NDSolve[] gives wrong solution:

```
{(8*Cos[φ[t]]*(4 - 4*(1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2) - 
   (-2.8284271250218156 + 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2)*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2)/
 (1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2) + 
(8*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])*(4 - 4*(1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2) - 
   (-2.8284271250218156 + 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2)*Sin[φ[t]]^3*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2)/
 (1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2)^2 + 
(4*Sin[φ[t]]^2*Derivative[1][φ][t]*(8*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])*Sin[φ[t]]*
    Derivative[1][φ][t] + 8*(-2.8284271250218156 + 4*Cos[φ[t]])*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]))/
 (1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2) + 
(4*Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t] + (5.656854250043631*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t])/
   Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2] - 
  (8*Cos[φ[t]]*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t])/
   Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2])*
 ((5.656854250043631*Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t])/
   Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2] - (8*Cos[φ[t]]^2*Derivative[1][φ][t])/
   Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2] - 4*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t] + 
  (8*Sin[φ[t]]^2*Derivative[1][φ][t])/Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2] + 
  (5.656854250043631*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])*Sin[φ[t]]^2*Derivative[1][φ][t])/
   (1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2)^(3/2) - 
  (8*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])*Cos[φ[t]]*Sin[φ[t]]^2*Derivative[1][φ][t])/
   (1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2)^(3/2)) + 
Derivative[1][φ][t]*
 (-((2*(4 - Sqrt[(1/4)*(-Cos[γ[t]] - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2 + (1/4)*(Sin[γ[t]] + 4*Sin[φ[t]])^2])^2*
     ((1/2)*(Sin[γ[t]] + 4*Sin[φ[t]])*(Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t] + 
        4*Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]) + (1/2)*(-Cos[γ[t]] - 4*Cos[φ[t]])*
       (Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t] + 4*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t])))/
    (5*Sqrt[(1/4)*(-Cos[γ[t]] - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2 + (1/4)*(Sin[γ[t]] + 4*Sin[φ[t]])^2])) + 
  (2*(1 + Sqrt[(1/4)*(-Cos[γ[t]] - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2 + (1/4)*(Sin[γ[t]] + 4*Sin[φ[t]])^2])^2*
    ((1/2)*(Sin[γ[t]] + 4*Sin[φ[t]])*(Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t] + 
       4*Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]) + (1/2)*(-Cos[γ[t]] - 4*Cos[φ[t]])*
      (Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t] + 4*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t])))/
   (5*Sqrt[(1/4)*(-Cos[γ[t]] - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2 + (1/4)*(Sin[γ[t]] + 4*Sin[φ[t]])^2])) + 
(4*(4 - 4*(1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2) - (-2.8284271250218156 + 4*Cos[φ[t]])^
    2)*Sin[φ[t]]^2*Derivative[2][φ][t])/(1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2) + 
((4/15)*(4 - Sqrt[(1/4)*(-Cos[γ[t]] - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2 + (1/4)*(Sin[γ[t]] + 4*Sin[φ[t]])^2])^3 + 
  (4/15)*(1 + Sqrt[(1/4)*(-Cos[γ[t]] - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2 + (1/4)*(Sin[γ[t]] + 4*Sin[φ[t]])^2])^3)*
 Derivative[2][φ][t] + (4*Cos[φ[t]] + (5.656854250043631*Sin[φ[t]])/
   Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2] - (8*Cos[φ[t]]*Sin[φ[t]])/
   Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2])*
 ((5.656854250043631*Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2)/
   Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2] - (8*Cos[φ[t]]^2*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2)/
   Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2] - 4*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2 + 
  (8*Sin[φ[t]]^2*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2)/Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2] + 
  (5.656854250043631*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])*Sin[φ[t]]^2*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2)/
   (1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2)^(3/2) - 
  (8*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])*Cos[φ[t]]*Sin[φ[t]]^2*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2)/
   (1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2)^(3/2) + 4*Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[2][φ][t] + 
  (5.656854250043631*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[2][φ][t])/
   Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2] - 
  (8*Cos[φ[t]]*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[2][φ][t])/
   Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2]) + 
50*(-2*Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t]*(Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t] + 
    Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]) + 2*Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t]*
   (Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t] + Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]) + 
  2*Cos[γ[t]]*((-Sin[γ[t]])*Derivative[1][γ][t]^2 - Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t]*
     Derivative[1][φ][t] + Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[2][γ][t] + Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[2][φ][t]) + 
  2*Sin[γ[t]]*(Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t]^2 + Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t]*
     Derivative[1][φ][t] + Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[2][γ][t] + Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[2][φ][t])) + 
2*(2*((1/2)*Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t] + 2*Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t])*
   ((-(1/2))*Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t] - 2*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]) + 
  2*((1/2)*Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t] + 2*Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t])*
   ((1/2)*Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t] + 2*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]) + 
  2*((1/2)*Cos[γ[t]] + 2*Cos[φ[t]])*((-(1/2))*Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t]*
     Derivative[1][φ][t] - 2*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2 + 
    (1/2)*Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[2][φ][t] + 2*Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[2][φ][t]) + 
  2*((1/2)*Sin[γ[t]] + 2*Sin[φ[t]])*((1/2)*Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t]*Derivative[1][φ][t] + 
    2*Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2 + (1/2)*Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[2][φ][t] + 
    2*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[2][φ][t])) == -78.48*Sin[φ[t]] + 
(4*Cos[φ[t]]*(4 - 4*(1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2) - 
   (-2.8284271250218156 + 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2)*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2)/
 (1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2) + 
(4*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])*(4 - 4*(1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2) - 
   (-2.8284271250218156 + 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2)*Sin[φ[t]]^3*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2)/
 (1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2)^2 + 
(2*Sin[φ[t]]^2*(8*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])*Sin[φ[t]] + 
   8*(-2.8284271250218156 + 4*Cos[φ[t]])*Sin[φ[t]])*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2)/
 (1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2) + 
(1/2)*(-((2*(2*(-Cos[γ[t]] - 4*Cos[φ[t]])*Sin[φ[t]] + 2*Cos[φ[t]]*(Sin[γ[t]] + 4*Sin[φ[t]]))*
     (4 - Sqrt[(1/4)*(-Cos[γ[t]] - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2 + (1/4)*(Sin[γ[t]] + 4*Sin[φ[t]])^2])^2)/
    (5*Sqrt[(1/4)*(-Cos[γ[t]] - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2 + (1/4)*(Sin[γ[t]] + 4*Sin[φ[t]])^2])) + 
  (2*(2*(-Cos[γ[t]] - 4*Cos[φ[t]])*Sin[φ[t]] + 2*Cos[φ[t]]*(Sin[γ[t]] + 4*Sin[φ[t]]))*
    (1 + Sqrt[(1/4)*(-Cos[γ[t]] - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2 + (1/4)*(Sin[γ[t]] + 4*Sin[φ[t]])^2])^2)/
   (5*Sqrt[(1/4)*(-Cos[γ[t]] - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2 + (1/4)*(Sin[γ[t]] + 4*Sin[φ[t]])^2]))*
 Derivative[1][φ][t]^2 + (4*Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t] + 
  (5.656854250043631*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t])/
   Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2] - 
  (8*Cos[φ[t]]*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t])/
   Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2])*
 ((5.656854250043631*Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t])/
   Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2] - (8*Cos[φ[t]]^2*Derivative[1][φ][t])/
   Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2] - 4*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t] + 
  (8*Sin[φ[t]]^2*Derivative[1][φ][t])/Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2] + 
  (5.656854250043631*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])*Sin[φ[t]]^2*Derivative[1][φ][t])/
   (1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2)^(3/2) - 
  (8*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])*Cos[φ[t]]*Sin[φ[t]]^2*Derivative[1][φ][t])/
   (1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2)^(3/2)) + 
2*(-4*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]*((1/2)*Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t] + 
    2*Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]) + 4*Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]*
   ((1/2)*Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t] + 2*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t])), 
(100 - 100*(Cos[γ[t]]^2 + Sin[γ[t]]^2))*Derivative[2][γ][t] + 
50*(-2*Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t]*(Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t] + 
    Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]) + 2*Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t]*
   (Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t] + Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]) + 
  2*Cos[γ[t]]*((-Sin[γ[t]])*Derivative[1][γ][t]^2 - Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t]*
     Derivative[1][φ][t] + Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[2][γ][t] + Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[2][φ][t]) + 
  2*Sin[γ[t]]*(Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t]^2 + Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t]*
     Derivative[1][φ][t] + Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[2][γ][t] + Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[2][φ][t])) == 
-1981.62*Sin[γ[t]] + 
(1/2)*(-((2*((1/2)*(-Cos[γ[t]] - 4*Cos[φ[t]])*Sin[γ[t]] + (1/2)*Cos[γ[t]]*
       (Sin[γ[t]] + 4*Sin[φ[t]]))*(4 - Sqrt[(1/4)*(-Cos[γ[t]] - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2 + 
         (1/4)*(Sin[γ[t]] + 4*Sin[φ[t]])^2])^2)/
    (5*Sqrt[(1/4)*(-Cos[γ[t]] - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2 + (1/4)*(Sin[γ[t]] + 4*Sin[φ[t]])^2])) + 
  (2*((1/2)*(-Cos[γ[t]] - 4*Cos[φ[t]])*Sin[γ[t]] + (1/2)*Cos[γ[t]]*(Sin[γ[t]] + 4*Sin[φ[t]]))*
    (1 + Sqrt[(1/4)*(-Cos[γ[t]] - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2 + (1/4)*(Sin[γ[t]] + 4*Sin[φ[t]])^2])^2)/
   (5*Sqrt[(1/4)*(-Cos[γ[t]] - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2 + (1/4)*(Sin[γ[t]] + 4*Sin[φ[t]])^2]))*
 Derivative[1][φ][t]^2 + 50*(2*(Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t] + Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t])*
   ((-Sin[γ[t]])*Derivative[1][γ][t] - Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]) + 
  2*(Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t] + Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t])*
   (Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t] + Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t])) + 
2*((-Sin[γ[t]])*Derivative[1][φ][t]*((1/2)*Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t] + 
    2*Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]) + Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]*
   ((1/2)*Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t] + 2*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]))}
```

These are the same ODEs with the substitution of the same parameter values was made in another nb file (now NDSolve[] gives correct result) :

```
{(8*Cos[φ[t]]*(4 - 4*(1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2) - 
   (-2.8284271250218156 + 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2)*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2)/
 (1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2) + 
(8*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])*(4 - 4*(1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2) - 
   (-2.8284271250218156 + 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2)*Sin[φ[t]]^3*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2)/
 (1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2)^2 - 
(4*Sin[φ[t]]^2*Derivative[1][φ][t]*(-8*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])*Sin[φ[t]]*
    Derivative[1][φ][t] - 8*(-2.8284271250218156 + 4*Cos[φ[t]])*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]))/
 (1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2) + 
(4*(4 - 4*(1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2) - (-2.8284271250218156 + 4*Cos[φ[t]])^
    2)*Sin[φ[t]]^2*Derivative[2][φ][t])/(1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2) + 
((4/15)*(4 - Sqrt[(9/4)*Cos[φ[t]]^2 + (9/4)*Sin[φ[t]]^2])^3 + 
  (4/15)*(1 + Sqrt[(9/4)*Cos[φ[t]]^2 + (9/4)*Sin[φ[t]]^2])^3)*Derivative[2][φ][t] + 
50*(2*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]*(Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t] - 
    Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]) - 2*Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]*
   (Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t] - Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]) - 
  2*Cos[φ[t]]*((-Sin[γ[t]])*Derivative[1][γ][t]^2 + Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2 + 
    Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[2][γ][t] - Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[2][φ][t]) - 
  2*Sin[φ[t]]*(Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t]^2 - Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2 + 
    Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[2][γ][t] - Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[2][φ][t])) + 
2*(3*Cos[φ[t]]*((-(3/2))*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2 + (3/2)*Cos[φ[t]]*
     Derivative[2][φ][t]) + 3*Sin[φ[t]]*((3/2)*Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2 + 
    (3/2)*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[2][φ][t])) + 
(1/2)*(2*(0. + 4*Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t] + (5.656854250043631*Sin[φ[t]]*
      Derivative[1][φ][t])/Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2] - 
    (8*Cos[φ[t]]*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t])/
     Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2])*
   (0. + (5.656854250043631*Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t])/
     Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2] - (8*Cos[φ[t]]^2*Derivative[1][φ][t])/
     Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2] - 4*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t] + 
    (8*Sin[φ[t]]^2*Derivative[1][φ][t])/Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2] + 
    (5.656854250043631*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])*Sin[φ[t]]^2*Derivative[1][φ][t])/
     (1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2)^(3/2) - 
    (8*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])*Cos[φ[t]]*Sin[φ[t]]^2*Derivative[1][φ][t])/
     (1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2)^(3/2)) + 
  2*(0. + 4*Cos[φ[t]] + (5.656854250043631*Sin[φ[t]])/
     Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2] - (8*Cos[φ[t]]*Sin[φ[t]])/
     Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2])*
   (0. + (5.656854250043631*Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2)/
     Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2] - (8*Cos[φ[t]]^2*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2)/
     Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2] - 4*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2 + 
    (8*Sin[φ[t]]^2*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2)/Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2] + 
    (5.656854250043631*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])*Sin[φ[t]]^2*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2)/
     (1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2)^(3/2) - 
    (8*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])*Cos[φ[t]]*Sin[φ[t]]^2*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2)/
     (1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2)^(3/2) + 4*Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[2][φ][t] + 
    (5.656854250043631*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[2][φ][t])/
     Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2] - 
    (8*Cos[φ[t]]*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[2][φ][t])/
     Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2])) == 
0. + 922.14*Sin[φ[t]] + (4*Cos[φ[t]]*(4 - 4*(1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2) - 
   (-2.8284271250218156 + 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2)*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2)/
 (1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2) + 
(4*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])*(4 - 4*(1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2) - 
   (-2.8284271250218156 + 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2)*Sin[φ[t]]^3*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2)/
 (1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2)^2 - 
(2*Sin[φ[t]]^2*(-8*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])*Sin[φ[t]] - 
   8*(-2.8284271250218156 + 4*Cos[φ[t]])*Sin[φ[t]])*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2)/
 (1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2) + 
(0. + 4*Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t] + (5.656854250043631*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t])/
   Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2] - 
  (8*Cos[φ[t]]*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t])/
   Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2])*
 (0. + (5.656854250043631*Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t])/
   Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2] - (8*Cos[φ[t]]^2*Derivative[1][φ][t])/
   Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2] - 4*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t] + 
  (8*Sin[φ[t]]^2*Derivative[1][φ][t])/Sqrt[1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2] + 
  (5.656854250043631*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])*Sin[φ[t]]^2*Derivative[1][φ][t])/
   (1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2)^(3/2) - 
  (8*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])*Cos[φ[t]]*Sin[φ[t]]^2*Derivative[1][φ][t])/
   (1 - (1/4)*(2.8284271250218156 - 4*Cos[φ[t]])^2)^(3/2)) + 
50*(2*Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]*(Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t] - 
    Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]) - 2*Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]*
   (Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t] - Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t])), 
(100 - 100*(Cos[γ[t]]^2 + Sin[γ[t]]^2))*Derivative[2][γ][t] + 
50*(-2*Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t]*(Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t] - 
    Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]) + 2*Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t]*
   (Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t] - Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]) + 
  2*Cos[γ[t]]*((-Sin[γ[t]])*Derivative[1][γ][t]^2 + Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2 + 
    Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[2][γ][t] - Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[2][φ][t]) + 
  2*Sin[γ[t]]*(Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t]^2 - Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]^2 + 
    Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[2][γ][t] - Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[2][φ][t])) == 
-981.*Sin[γ[t]] + 50*(-2*Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t]*(Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t] - 
    Cos[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]) + 2*Cos[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t]*
   (Sin[γ[t]]*Derivative[1][γ][t] - Sin[φ[t]]*Derivative[1][φ][t]))}
```

Comment: Prior to copy and paste into MSE, convert the cells to `InputForm` (or `Raw InputForm`).

Comment: @Bob Hanlon - I did it with Raw InputForm - however the formatting is still not pretty. The first set of 3 ODes (for which NDSolve[] doesnt wor well) are all displayed as a first block of code. The second set of ODEs  (for which NDSolve gives correct result ) is partly displayed as a code and partly as a text under it.

Comment: Thanks @Goofy for improvment of code display

Comment: You're welcome. It's too bad there isn't an easy way to turn all the `Derivative[1][f][x]` into `f'[x]`. At least I don't know how, other than to paste it all into a real editor.

Comment: @lodzki What about this question? There is no `NDSolve` in the code above.  Could you show line with `NDSolve`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev But NDSolve command is not a problem here. Problem is why we get different ODEs depending on place we substitute the parameters (of these ODEs) with numerical values. I ve found out that if I do this substitution right before NDSolve command the code is working. And it's not working if I do it at the top of my code - the place where ODEs have not been created yet.

Comment: @AlexTrounev This is strange - maybe this is error in mathematica software itself.

Comment: @lodzki How we can test your problem while we don't know what do you compute?

Comment: Please provide the explicit input that uses `NDSolve` that you are using to get these outputs. Surely, this is just a matter of copy & paste for you. Anyone else is left with an infinite number of possible inputs. The one which you have used will be of great benefit, and it is better to include such things in any case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the numerical data values should be put right before the NDSolve command execution (not earlier)-then it can handle this really well. I dont know why it is such a difference for that solver but I was also said that it is good practice to do it that way.

Comment: Could you provide more details?

Comment: I can tell you that from now on I'm doing it in this manner on many different codes and this approach still works. Maybe it means that symbolic computations shouldnt be mixed with numerical ones? I mean "keeping computations symbolic as long as it is possible and only shift to numerical when it is required" seems a good practice.

Comment: Please provide the code used for this answer & note the changes from what you will/should provide in your original question post. As it is, this is more appropriate as a comment to provide additional clarification to your original question post.

Comment: Ok I will do it in a week time.